# Bluemix: Is it possible to 'talk' with Bluemix app through IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mq

I'm wondering if an external app could 'talk' to Bluemix app using IBM MQ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluemix currently offers the MQ Light service which can be used for messaging to IBM MQ (formerly WebSphere MQ)

[MessageHub](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/index.html) also allows you to use the MQ Light APIs via Bluemix to do messaging.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that external app (in my datacenter) could 'talk' with Bluemix app via MQ Light and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that.  If the application in your datacenter can connect to the Bluemix MessageHub then it can use the MQ Light API for messaging to communicate.

Answer (score 3):

A slight clarification on MQ Light in the previous answer.

An MQ Light application in Bluemix can communicate with IBM MQ in your datacenter (via the SecureGateway), but if you are running an instance of the MQ LIght service in Bluemix, the service itself cannot be connected to IBM MQ.